# smarty, send to file date

Tags: php, smarty

I have in a PHP file this array:

```
array(1, 2, 3);
```

How can I send this array to a Smarty .tpl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$smartyobject->assign("varname", array(1, 2, 3));
```

after this, you can access it as `{$varname}` (or whatever you set your delimiters to)